# Ruby On Rails: Cannot show Controller#Action view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to show my view (posts/index.html.erb) but it is not showing up.

My routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :posts
devise_for :users
root 'posts#index'
end
```

Even if I try manually localhost:3000/posts/index it is not being loaded.

It just shows the default (layouts/application.html.erb):

{A Bootstrap Starter Template
Complete with pre-defined file paths that you won't have to change!!
Bootstrap v3.3.7
jQuery v1.11.1}

the (posts/index.html.erb) should display this:

```
<h1>Posts#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/posts/index.html.erb</p>
```

Any ideas what I am missing? I have done other applications in rails also and compared the code with this application but I cant find out what's wrong.

Thankful for any help!

Best regards,
Conan

Answer (score 1):

I got it working, forgot the <%= yield %> in application.html.erb!